# Custom styled checkbox in wrong place in Safari (desktop/mobile) and Chrome (mobile only)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, forms, mailchimp

I'm having issues with a checkbox I've styled using the w3schools method [here](https://w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp). In Safari (mobile/desktop), the checkbox is to the right. In Chrome (mobile only), it's also to the right. It's working properly in Chrome on the desktop (on the left side). The code snippet below is also looking wonky—the page is [here](https://melaniepatterson.com/linkinbio/). The checkbox span is inside the label so I'm not sure why it's not working. Do you see what's going on?

```css
.mc4wp-form {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.newsletter-form label {
  display: none;
}


/*.newsletter-form div {
    width: 100%;
} */

.mc4wp-form input[name="FNAME"],
.mc4wp-form input[name="LNAME"] {
  height: 65px;
  max-width: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #EFE9E4;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-color: #123526;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-left: 1px solid;
}

.mc4wp-form input[name="FNAME"]::placeholder,
.mc4wp-form input[name="LNAME"]::placeholder,
.mc4wp-form input[type="email"]::placeholder {
  color: #123526;
  opacity: 1;
  /* Firefox */
}

.mc4wp-form input[name="FNAME"]::-ms-input-placeholder,
.mc4wp-form input[name="LNAME"]::-ms-input-placeholder,
.mc4wp-form input[type="email"]::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #123526;
  opacity: 1;
  /* Firefox */
}

.mc4wp-form input[name="FNAME"] {
  border-right: 0px;
}

.mc4wp-form input[name="LNAME"] {
  border-right: 1px solid;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .mc4wp-form input[type="email"] {
    height: 65px;
    float: left;
    max-width: 75%;
    width: 75%;
    background-color: #EFE9E4;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1.5%;
    border-color: #123526 !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    border-left: 1px solid;
    border-right: 1px solid;
    border-top: 0px solid;
    font-family: 'Space Grotesk', Grotesk;
  }
  .mc4wp-form input[type="submit"] {
    height: 65px;
    float: left;
    max-width: 25% !important;
    width: 25% !important;
    background-color: #123526;
    color: #EFE9E4;
    margin-bottom: 1.5%;
    border: 0px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-family: 'Space Grotesk', Grotesk;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .mc4wp-form input[type="email"] {
    height: 65px;
    float: left;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #EFE9E4;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-color: #123526 !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    border-left: 1px solid;
    border-right: 1px solid;
    border-top: 0px solid;
    font-family: 'Space Grotesk', Grotesk;
  }
  .mc4wp-form input[type="submit"] {
    height: 65px;
    float: left;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    background-color: #123526;
    color: #EFE9E4;
    margin-bottom: 1.5%;
    border: 0px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-family: 'Space Grotesk', Grotesk;
  }
}

input[type=text],
input[type=url] {
  color: #123526;
  font-family: 'Space Grotesk', Grotesk;
}

.mc4wp-form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #878721;
}

input:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}

input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
textarea:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:hover,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:focus,
select:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill:hover,
select:-webkit-autofill:focus {
  border-color: #123526;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #123526;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px #EFE9E4 inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px #EFE9E4 inset;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px #EFE9E4 inset;
  transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.mc4wp-form-basic label {
  display: inline
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .form-terms {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .form-terms {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
}

.form-terms a {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.form-terms a:hover {
  font-weight: normal;
}


/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */

.form-terms input {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}


/* Create a custom checkbox */

.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0 !important;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #123526;
  background-color: #EFE9E4;
}


/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */

.form-terms:hover input~.checkmark {
  background-color: #EFE9E4;
}


/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */

.form-terms input:checked~.checkmark {
  background-color: #123526;
}


/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */

.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}


/* Show the checkmark when checked */

.form-terms input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}


/* Style the checkmark/indicator */

.form-terms .checkmark:after {
  left: 6px;
  top: 3px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid #EFE9E4;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="mc4wp-form"><input type="text" name="FNAME" placeholder="First name" class="form-first" aria-label="First name" required="">
  <input type="text" name="LNAME" placeholder="Last name" class="form-last" aria-label="Last name" required="">
  <input type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Email address" class="form-email" aria-label="Email" required />
  <input type="submit" value="Sign up" class="form-submit" aria-label="Sign up" />
  <center><label class="form-terms">  
      <input type="checkbox" name="AGREE_TO_TERMS" value="1" aria-label="I have read and agree to the terms &amp; conditions" required=""> <a href="https://melaniepatterson.com/terms-conditions" class="wave" target="_blank">I have read and agree to the terms &amp; conditions</a>
   <span class="checkmark"></span> 
  </label></center>
</div>
```

I've also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47410396/checkbox-styling-doesnt-work-on-safari-mobile), but it's not quite the same issue.

[image: Form with checkbox on the right side instead to the left of terms]
[image: Correct checkbox on desktop in Chrome]

Comment: Hi @melanie, Please ``mark this as an answer`` if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are some HTML structuring issues and some CSS changes required to have your solution. There is no need to style `absolute` the `checkmark` span as it is sufficient to have `display: flex` to the parent label.

The style needs to be updated as follows.

CSS:

```
.mc4wp-form-basic input[type=checkbox], .mc4wp-form-basic input[type=radio]{
   display: none;
}
.checkmark {
    /*position: absolute;*/
    position: relative;
    left: auto !important;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #123526;
    background-color: #EFE9E4;
    
    
    /*New added css*/
    margin: 0 10px 0 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.mc4wp-form-basic label {
    /*display: inline;*/
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

HTML:
The `checkmark` span tag needs to be placed before the `a` tag.

Check that abovesaid solution. Hope it helps!